# how to set java library path for processing

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm using PDE to run a Processing sketch, and I get the following error:

> **Verify that the `java.library.path` property is correctly set.**

Could anyone of you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can set it on the command line thus:

```
java -Djava.library.path=... <existing arguments (classpath, name of class to run etc.)>
```

and point it to the *directory* containing the relevant library.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I tried `java -Djava.library.path=C:\Python33` but it gave me the usage of `java.exe`

Comment: @papaiatis You still have to specify the name of the class to run. The `-D` is in addition to what you normally specify when running a java from the command-line.

Answer (score 14):

Before `System.loadLibrary("")`, use the following code to check you `java.library.path`

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

Generally, the `java.library.path`=`/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib`

Provides several options for:

- `$ sudo cp libxxx.so /usr/lib/jni`
- `java -Djava.library.path=_path of so_  xxx`

Comment: Instead of changing your source code, you use the Expressions tab in the debug perspective and put System.getProperty("java.library.path") to show you what it's value is.

Answer (score 12):

In Eclipse, I did this to get OpenCV working:

1. In the **Run** menu, select **Run Configuration**.
2. Go to the **(x)=Arguments** tab of your sketch.
3. Add this in the **VM arguments** field:

   ```
   -Djava.library.path="/path/to/OpenCV/library"
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Your `library.path` is fine, what you need to do is to drop  prefix `lib` and suffix `.so` from your `System.loadLibrary( "..." )`. On Linux or "linux-android" those will be automatically added by JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion of above all answers (short form) is as follows:

Lets say my lib folder path is `lib/`

Then to add in the library path: run below command:

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib/ -jar  mySampleJar.jar
```