# How to save a file as rdf in Protege 4.3?

Tags: oracle, ontology

I have made an ontology on Protege. it has . owl extension. I am trying to import this ontology in oracle 12c using jena. but model. Read method requires an rdf file. I am giving  the  code as well as error. Kindly help me in this case.

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path
    at oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.Oracle.<init>(Oracle.java:207)
    at test.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:26)
```

**code** package test;

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.GraphOracleSem;
import oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.ModelOracleSem;
import oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.Oracle;
import oracle.spatial.rdf.client.jena.OracleUtils;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.GraphUtil;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Triple;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;

public class TestJena{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //String szJdbcURL = args[0];
        //String szUser = args[1];
        //String szPasswd = args[2];
        //String szModelName = args[3];
        // in memory Jena Model
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        InputStream is = FileManager.get().open("E:/abcd.owl");
        model.read(is, "", "RDF/XML");
        is.close();

        Oracle oracle = new Oracle("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@", "c##hr_admin","Hira123");

        ModelOracleSem modelDest = ModelOracleSem.createOracleSemModel(oracle,"M1");
        GraphOracleSem g = modelDest.getGraph();
        g.dropApplicationTableIndex();
        int method = 2; // try bulk loader
        String tbs = "SYSAUX"; // can be customized
        if (method == 0) {
            System.out.println("start incremental");
            modelDest.add(model);
            System.out.println("end size " + modelDest.size());
        }
        else if (method == 1) {
            System.out.println("start batch load");
            g.getBulkUpdateHandler().addInBatch(
            GraphUtil.findAll(model.getGraph()), tbs);
            System.out.println("end size " + modelDest.size());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("start bulk load");
            g.getBulkUpdateHandler().addInBulk(
            GraphUtil.findAll(model.getGraph()), tbs);
            System.out.println("end size " + modelDest.size());
        }
        g.rebuildApplicationTableIndex();
        long lCount = g.getCount(Triple.ANY);
        System.out.println("Asserted triples count: " + lCount);
        model.close();
        OracleUtils.dropSemanticModel(oracle, "M1");
        oracle.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the file to RDF: under the assumption that the format you used for the ontology is RDF/XML (the default), all that is needed is changing the file extension.

Regarding the error you post, you are missing a binary library. You need to set java.library.path to point at the folder containing the library mentioned in the error.
See for example [how to set java library path for processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734207/how-to-set-java-library-path-for-processing) for how to do this.