# Can't find dependent libraries errorlevel=1

Tags: jmeter

While running bat file in jmeter it gives me  Can't find dependent libraries
errorlevel=1 error. Can anyone pls provide me the solution

I tried to run jmeter

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and edit your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`Can't find dependent libraries` is one of error messages for the [UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) which happens when a .dll (or .so) file is not in the [java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734207/how-to-set-java-library-path-for-processing)

JMeter per se doesn't load any native libraries (at least as of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)) so if you're using a plugin which does - check its documentation regarding how the native libraries need to be provided.

If you're not using any plugins the error means that your Java installation is broken somehow, I would suggest performing clean installation of the [JDK](https://openjdk.org/)