# How to do connection of JMeter with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, jmeter, performance-testing, database-performance, jmeter-5.0

I wan to test the SQL Server database with JMeter but I am not able to figure out how to make the connection. I am using SQLExpress and using the windows type authentication.
The below figure shows my SQL Server Authentication method

[image]

I am trying to configure JMeter with below configuration

[image]

I tried to do this but I am getting the below error

> Response message:java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' for connect URL ' jdbc:sqlserver://219.65.110.50;intanceName=./SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind'

And what will be the username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `;integratedSecurity=true` parameter to the end of your JDBC URL
2. Username and password can be left blank as the authentication will be done by Windows
3. Make sure that `mssql-jdbc_auth-<version>-<arch>.dll`  file is present in [`java.library.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734207/how-to-set-java-library-path-for-processing)
4. Make sure that `mssql-jdbc-<version>.<jre-version.jar` is in JMeter Classpath (lib folder of your JMeter installation or in the folder where [`user.classpath` JMeter Property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) points to)

More information: [Connecting with Integrated Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/legacy/ms378428(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#connecting-with-integrated-authentication)