# no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE Web Application which connects to a SQL Server 2008 instance. I don't have any problem connecting and retrieving to all my tables, except for one of them. The error in the Tomcat log is:

> WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Comment: You can try the answer on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949890/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path

Answer (score 56):

1) Download **the JDBC Driver** [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

2) unzip the file and go to **sqljdbc_version\fra\auth\x86** or **\x64** 

 3) copy the **sqljdbc_auth.dll** to **C:\Program Files\Java\jre_Version\bin**

 4) Finally restart eclipse

Comment: Could you please add a little more description to the solution you provide?

Comment: @AmineSoumiaa I believe that it should go under bin under JDK not under JRE. I just tried.

Comment: Perfect answer... easy method. Thanks @AmineSoumiaa

Comment: why do we need to add something to our java\bin folder? Is not there any other method only we import via gradle and maven?

Answer (score 21):

Here are the steps if you want to do this from Eclipse :

1) Create a folder 'sqlauth' in your C: drive, and copy the dll file ***sqljdbc_auth.dll*** to the folder

1) Go to **Run> Run Configurations**

2) Choose the '**Arguments**' tab for your class

3) Add the below code in **VM arguments**:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\\sqlauth"
```

4) Hit 'Apply' and click 'Run'

Feel free to try other [methods](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/04/what-is-javalibrarypath-how-to-set-in-Eclipse.html) .

Comment: great option here leveraging the `java.library.path` argument. saved me a ton of headache as the users can't copy/paste to the `C:\Program Files` folder. thanks!

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much. I was driving myself mad going through dozens of different approaches that don't work.

Comment: The methods link that you added was a useful read that helped explain a little of the why.  Thank you for this solution which I finally came to after two days on this issue.  Very frustrating that Classpath doesnt seem to do its job, but perhaps it is my newness to Java. . .I am not a fan thus far due to these fragilities

Answer (score 11):

For easy fix follow these steps:

1. goto: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url#Connectingintegrated
2. Download the JDBC file and extract to your preferred location
3. open the auth folder matching your OS x64 or x86
4. copy sqljdbc_auth.dll file
5. paste in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_version\bin
6. restart either eclipse or netbeans

Comment: This one worked for me. I am trying to read SQL Server table using Apache Spark, which required JDBC Driver.

Answer (score 6):

The error is clear, isn't it?

You've not added the path where sqljdbc_auth.dll is present. Find out in the system where the DLL is and add that to your classpath.

And if that also doesn't work, add the folder where the DLL is present (I'm assuming \Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\auth\x86) to your PATH variable.

Again if you're going via ant or cmd you have to explicitly mention the path using -Djava.library.path=[path to MS_SQL_AUTH_DLL]

Comment: The problem is here: I have searched internet, the response was like your response but I DON'T HAVE THIS DLL FILE IN  MY COMPUTER!!!!

Comment: Well then we have a problem, rite? I think you haven't installed the driver at all! Go to this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx . They give step by step on how to install and use

Comment: @andrewrjones The JDBC driver does. However, it cannot connect using a Trusted Connection without this DLL. You can do a username/password connection - just not a trusted connection.

Comment: For me adding to CLASSPATH was not enough, had to add to Path too

Comment: It's not clear at all. I add maven dependency, it should be there, why do I have to manually download and install it?

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered the same problem but within my own application.
I didn't like the solution with copying the dll since it's not very convenient so I did some research and came up with the following programmatic solution.

Basically, before doing any connections to SQL server, you have to add the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to path.. which is easy to say:

`PathHelper.appendToPath("C:\\sqljdbc_6.2\\enu\\auth\\x64");`

once you know how to do it:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class PathHelper {
    public static void appendToPath(String dir){

        String path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        path = dir + ";" + path;
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);

        try {

            final Field sysPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            sysPathsField.setAccessible(true);
            sysPathsField.set(null, null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Now integration authentication works like a charm :).

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730111/1734640 for letting me figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use windows authentication and I tried every suggested solution out there but with no success till I changed the name of the auth file as follows:

old-name: mssql-jdbc_auth-10.2.0.x64.dll

new-name: sqljdbc_auth.dll

And then it worked!

I looked up for this case to understand it more, apparently for Windows operating systems, the driver looks for sqljdbc_auth.dll by default.

Here is a useful link I've found:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/feature-dependencies-of-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

To resolve I did the following:

1. Copied `sqljdbc_auth.dll` into dir: `C:\Windows\System32`
2. Restarted my application

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by:

1. Upgrading com.microsoft.sqlserver from 6.1.0.jre8 to 10.1.0.jre8-preview:

   ```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0.jre8-preview</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Adding missing dependency:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
3. Using the following jdbc connection:

> jdbc:sqlserver://;authenticationScheme=NTLM;integratedSecurity=true;domain=;databasename=;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;user=;password=