# Kerberos Authentication Error - Sqoop import from SQL into HDFS via Hive

Tags: java, sql-server, hive, kerberos, sqoop

I am giving the following Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName:1433;databaseName=TESTDB;integratedSecurity=true" \
    --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
    --table dbo.test_table \
    --username hduser \
    -P \
    --hive-import \
    --create-hive-table \
    --hive-table test_table
```

and getting the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not
>   configured for integrated authentication.
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

**EDIT**

The solution for the above error was to add `authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos` to the connection string.

For Eg:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server_name:1433;database=db_name;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos" \
    --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver \
    --table Table_Name \
    --username username \
    -P \
    --target-dir /path/to/destination \
    --columns "col1, col2, col3" \
    --split-by col1 -m 4
```

Now I could list the databases and tables on the SQL server. All good till now.

But then, I am getting the Kerberos authentication error!!!

> Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: No
>   valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any
>   Kerberos tgt)

Get me a beer guys!!!

Comment: please check here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949890/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path

Comment: This is a Linux server. 
Added authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos to the connection string. 

Now am getting new errors such as: Defective token detected.(Mechanism level: AP_REP token id does not match!)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an firewall problem.

Reason:If you  are using this Port number'1433' then you have to enable this port access in Windows Firewall.

Solution:

Just Turn Off the windows firewall while run this sqoop Job [OR]  Enable the firewall rule for this port '1433'

Hope this really helpful for you.

Comment: Now, the command runs without error, but i cannot see tables created in my hive database.