# Connect to MSSQL from Spring boot application using windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows, spring-boot, unix

I am currently using the below properties to connect to a remotely Mssql server from Java spring boot application:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://ip\\domain;databaseName=name
spring.datasource.username=abc
spring.datasource.password=def
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

The application runs from both windows and unix servers. I need now to start using the windows authentication instead of the db credentials. This is already configured and supported from MSSQL side. From Java spring boot this is not working. I tried to add to the url: integratedSecurity=true it said it cannot find a dll. I added sqljdbc_auth.dll to java jre bin folder and it didnt work.

Comment: any error you are getting??

Comment: Error: The domain is not trusted. I tried with kerberos since i will be deploying on unix. I added: ;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos then in the same spring boot properties file i added: -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf . In the conf file i was not sure what to add so i just added the following: default_realm = [domain name]
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
forwardable = yes // this also did not work. The new error said that Client not found in Kerberos database. Can you help? is it something missing from the server side?

Comment: @user666 : are you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: No i am currently using DB credentials

Answer (score 7):

I'm working on MS SQL Server 2016, Hibernate 5.3.7.Final and Spring bot 2.2.0. For me, adding this line to properties worked: (without jtds!)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:servername;databasename=your_db_name;integratedSecurity=true
```

You may also need these properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

And if you encounter a problem with "no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path".
You may refer to this answer [no sqljdbc_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949890/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path).

Comment: My connection string in `application.properties` work with few more parameters: 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://[name]:[port];DatabaseName=[db_name];encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;integratedSecurity=true;

Answer (score 1):

Try use jtds driver, and in apllication properties use:

```
    app.datasource.youraplication.jdbcUrl=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://yourBdHost/yourSchemaBd;domain=yourDomain
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the drivers from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Add the jar to your project Right Click on project - > Build Path -> Configure Build Path - > Libraries -> Add External JARs

Add "integratedSecurity=true" to your connection string and remove username and password