# How can we setup Spring Cloud Data Flow datasource to use Kerberos Auth8n

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'd like to install SCDF 2.6.x with an Oracle DB and Kerberos auth8n.
I am following the spring cloud data flow adocs in the source, and the online guides at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_oracle.

There's clarity on how to use an Oracle datasource, but only with username and password for authentication.

My aim is to be able to use Kerberos auth8n with an Oracle driver, and specify this in the server-config.yml for kubernetes deployment.

Comment: I am not sure about Kerberos auth8n but SCDF itself is a Spring Boot application and all you need is to set the appropriate datasource properties which you would set for a Spring Boot application to connect to Kerberos auth8n. Maybe something along the lines of what is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813704/connect-to-mssql-from-spring-boot-application-using-windows-authentication

Comment: @ IlayaperumalGopinathan Rather than specify username and password we would need to specify the Kerb config location (krb) and kdc files. Can I add those properties as Spring.datasource.xxx? Alternatively is there a way to override the default DataSource bean for the Skipper and Server projects? I am aware of using @EnableDataFlowServer for the server, is there a matching annotation for a Skipper server?