# Can't connect to a SQL Server from Weblogic

Tags: java, sql-server, weblogic

I got the job to make run a project that usually runs at OpenShift, on WebLogic 12.1.3.0, i changed many things, make mvn build a .war, added weblogic.xml, I had to set at application.properties the connection data that is located at OpenShift's environment variables.

Now, when I deploy at WebLogic my app, I have this problem:

> Login failed for user 'user'. ClientConnectionId...
>   and this: `SQL Error: 18456, SQLState: S0001`

So now I added at my springdatasource.url the integrated security;

```
...integratedSecurity=true;
```

With this last change, I got another problem at deploy, the next:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

and the weblogic logs:

> SQL Error: 18456, SQLState: S0001

Hope anybody can help me to finally deploy the app, I set the connection data at weblogic's datasources, I tested it and worked, so I know credentials are OK.

Comment: Have you tried these already : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949890/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path

Comment: See also: [no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36596844/390122).

Comment: Sory for the late guys, i added the .dll to my jre/bin like it says at that link. And now im getting this problem at deploy:
`Native Library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader`
So, first says that i have no .dll, and now it says that is tooking it from 2 sides wtf