# JDBC Connection to Microsoft SQL server using java

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm trying to establish a connection to Microsoft SQL server but I'm getting an error message. I'm using jdk-13.
According to what I've read online I had to install microsoft sql server and copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll and paste it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin. what I did but it still doesn't work. Can someone help me to solve this problem? thanks :)

```
Oct 30, 2019 10:00:33 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2338)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1929)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1917)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1061)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:833)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:716)
    at sqljdbc4@2.0/com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:841)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at jdbc/de.mySampleCode.jdbc.SampleCode.main(SampleCode.java:26)
```

Comment: Do you have the right `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in your PATH?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707056/no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path might help

Comment: Hi @Shloim yeah I guess I have the right sqljdbc_auth in my PATH. the error I'm getting now is : #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000057e1ca43,pid=10584, tid=11060
#

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I'm using jdk-13 and I tried that already but it doesn't I'm getting the following error: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000057e1ca43,pid=10584, tid=11060
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x13ca43]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client

Comment: @BeJay the error message says its Java 1.8.0_45-b14