# Connecting to SQL Server via DBeaver instead of SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication in DBeaver. Although I can easily connect via SQL Server Management Studio, DBeaver is generating a connection error:

> No sqljdbc auth in java.library.path

Not sure why unlike DBeaver, SQL Server Management Studio can connect without any problem, but is there any instruction on how to ensure right JDBC driver (I think 32 bit) is installed and configured so I can connect via DBeaver?

Version 6.3.5.202002151353

Comment: Perhaps this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707056/no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path

Comment: As the error message says: you need to include `sqlauth.dll` in the library path. And the DLL needs to match the Java "bitness" you are using (probably 64bit).