# Solr DIH not working with error no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, jdbc, solr

Using Solr 8.5.2 docker image, I need to import a data using DIH from SQL Server.

I am loading sqljdbc42.jar and copying it at /opt/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler/ to load the same.

I am getting following error:

> Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable
> to execute query....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no sqljdbc_auth in
> java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib,
> /usr/lib]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)   at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.(AuthenticationJNI.java:41)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3132)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

My SQL Server is hosted on remote Windows Server.

How to fix this and use DIH to import data from SQL Server with Docker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707056/no-sqljdbc-auth-in-java-library-path

Comment: Thanks Abhijt. This talks about installing this on Windows. I need to resolve the same on Ubuntu. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by removing parameter for integratedSecurity from connection string.