# Error while running app on android emulator

Tags: android

I am newbee in android developement. I am trying to compile and run downloaded application(GnuPG). when I run the compiled code onto android emulator, it stops working with an error.

logcat shows following details.

```
00:29:45.163: I/ActivityThread(522): Publishing provider info.guardianproject.gpg: info.guardianproject.gpg.KeyDataProvider
00:29:45.173: I/ActivityThread(522): Publishing provider info.guardianproject.gpg.PrivateFilesProvider: info.guardianproject.gpg.PrivateFilesProvider
00:29:45.203: I/GpgApplication(522): onCreate
00:29:45.233: W/dalvikvm(522): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Linfo/guardianproject/gpg/Posix;.<clinit>
00:29:45.233: D/AndroidRuntime(522): Shutting down VM
00:29:45.233: W/dalvikvm(522): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522): at info.guardianproject.gpg.NativeHelper.setup(NativeHelper.java:71)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at info.guardianproject.gpg.GpgApplication.onCreate(GpgApplication.java:38)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4244)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library posix not found
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
00:29:45.243: E/AndroidRuntime(522):    at info.guardianproject.gpg.Posix.<clinit>(Posix.java:17)
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong here?? Do i need to add any other library or i need to change some settings??

Comment: You are missing posix library. Add the required library. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You crash culprit is reported in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library posix not found
```

So basically you are missing the dynamic linked library on your device/project.