# How to insert triples into Parliament Triple Store with Jena Library

Tags: java, geospatial, jena, triplestore

Hi I want to add spatial based triple

`http://www.izmirdeafet.com/Disaster htp://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT> "htp://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84 POINT (8.46035239692792 51.48661096320327)"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/sf#wktLiteral>`

into parliament triple store with `jena` library in the below java code but ı have taken error in the below. I have spatial based ontology which ı add already into triple store.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    // set to false when running the second time to avoid recreating the graphs/index 
    boolean firstTime = true;
    // create spatial index factory and configure for GeoSPARQL. This is used
    // by the GraphStore whenever a new named graph is created.
    SpatialIndexFactory factory = new SpatialIndexFactory();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Constants.GEOMETRY_INDEX_TYPE,
                     Constants.GEOMETRY_INDEX_RTREE);
    properties.setProperty(Constants.GEOSPARQL_ENABLED,
                     Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    factory.configure(properties);

    // register factory
    IndexFactoryRegistry.getInstance().register(factory);

    // create a Parliament graph and graph store
    //KbGraph graph= KbGraphFactory.createNamedGraph();
    KbGraph graph = 
    KbGraphFactory.createDefaultGraph("file:C:\\ParliamentKB\\data\\");
    KbGraphStore graphStore = new KbGraphStore(graph);
    graphStore.initialize();

    if (firstTime) {
        // create spatial index from factory
        SpatialIndex index = factory.createIndex(graph, null);

        // register index with IndexManager
        IndexManager.getInstance().register(graph, null, factory, index);

        // the following tells the graph store that the graph is now an
        // indexing graph. This is necessary so that the next time Parliament
        // loads, the index is read in automatically.
        graphStore.setIndexingEnabled(KbGraphStore.DEFAULT_GRAPH_NODE, true);
    }

    // create a Jena model
    Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(graph);

    // load data
    String fileName =
    "C:\\Users\\Can\\Desktop\\DisasterOntologyEnglish\\disaster.rdf";
    RDFFormat dataFormat = RDFFormat.parseFilename(fileName);
    FileManager.get().readModel(model, fileName, dataFormat.toString());

    // get index and print size
    System.out.println(IndexManager.getInstance().
        getIndexes(graph).get(0).size());

    // do a spatial query
    String query = ""
    + "\nPREFIX my:  <http://somewhere/ApplicationSchema#>"
    + "\nPREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/OGC-GeoSPARQL/1.0/>"
    + "\nPREFIX geof: 
     <http://www.opengis.net/def/queryLanguage/OGC-GeoSPARQL/1.0/function/>"
    + "\nSELECT ?f" + "\nWHERE { my:A my:hasExactGeometry ?aGeom ."
    + "\n        ?aGeom geo:asWKT ?aWKT ."
    + "\n        ?f my:hasExactGeometry ?fGeom ."
    + "\n        ?fGeom geo:asWKT ?fWKT ."
    + "\n        FILTER (geof:sf-contains(?aWKT, ?fWKT) &&"
    + "\n                !sameTerm(?aGeom, ?fGeom)) " + "\n}";

    Query q = QueryFactory.create(query, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
    ResultSet rs = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model).execSelect();
    while (rs.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(rs.nextSolution());
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    no Parliament in   java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jni.Config.<clinit>(Config.java:184)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.KbGraphFactory.getKbConfigForDefaultGraph
         (KbGraphFactory.java:81)
    at com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.KbGraphFactory.createDefaultGraph
         (KbGraphFactory.java:38)
    at com.disaster.demo.GeoSPARQLTest.main(GeoSPARQLTest.java:46)
```

I think problem is coming from `createdefaultgraph` part:

you said dir path taken from `ParliamentConfig.txt`

```
  KbGraph graph = KbGraphFactory.createDefaultGraph("file:C:\\ParliamentKB\\data\\");
```

I coded like this but it didnt work.

Comment: Looks like the library you are trying to load (Parliament) is not being found in the correct location.  Examine the `java.library.path` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and see if the jni library is there

Answer (score 1):

The unsatisfied link error probably indicates that it can't find Parliament.dll in the java path.

**Check this SO for details about dll's in the java path:**
[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError no *****.dll in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path)

**Also, are you following the Parliament setup guide?**
http://parliament.semwebcentral.org/ParliamentUserGuide.pdf

You also might want to make sure you're using the right dll... it's been a while so I may be wrong, but I think there's 32 and 64 bit builds.

Answer (score 0):

In the Parliament User Guide (http://parliament.semwebcentral.org/ParliamentUserGuide.pdf), Section 2.8 on page 26 is devoted to troubleshooting these UnsatisfiedLinkError problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as per the exception thrown is due to gaps in cofiguration/establishing the Parliament environment variables. Please follow the ParliamentUserGuide as provided in the answers above. Once that is complete you will get and output like this:

`INFO [main] (KbGraphStore.java:163) - Adding named graph: <http://parliament.semwebcentral.org/parliament#MasterGraph> (graphDir = "master")
Apr 07, 2014 2:17:05 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory <init>
INFO: Setting the EPSG factory org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory to a 1800000ms timeout
Apr 07, 2014 2:17:05 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory <init>
INFO: Setting the EPSG factory org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DefaultFactory to a 1800000ms timeout
Apr 07, 2014 2:17:05 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory createDataSource
INFO: Building new data source for org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory
Apr 07, 2014 2:17:05 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory createBackingStore
INFO: Building backing store for org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory
Apr 07, 2014 2:17:05 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory createBackingStore
INFO: Creating cached EPSG database version 7.5.0. This operation may take a few minutes...
Apr 07, 2014 2:17:06 PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.PropertyAuthorityFactory <init>
WARNING: Axis elements found in a wkt definition, the force longitude first axis order hint might not be respected:
PROJCS["Google Projection",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295],AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST],AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]],PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0],PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0],PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0],PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0],PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0],UNIT["m", 1.0]]`

Only after which you can perform any operations on the model created, like adding triples and query.

Further to a Triple with spatial attribute: say you want to add a spatial co-ordinate to an Individual (eg. `individual`) you can use the following code snippet:

```
import com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.index.spatial.geosparql.datatypes.WKTLiteral;
import com.bbn.parliament.jena.graph.index.spatial.geosparql.vocabulary.*;
.
.
.
WKTLiteral geoLiteral = new WKTLiteral();
String value="Point(22.5 88.5)";// OR "POLYGON((22.5 88.5, 88.5 99.5, 99.5 22.5))"
individual.addLiteral(Geo.asWKT, model.createTypedLiteral(value, geoLiteral));
```

And the Trick for:

`KbGraph graph = KbGraphFactory.createDefaultGraph("file:C:\\ParliamentKB\\data\\");`
does not work, I don't know why! so you may need to specify th epath in ParliamentCOnfig.txt itself.