# Not able to execute a class with external class path

Tags: java, compilation, openoffice.org

I have a class Test.java

```
import com.sun.star.bridge.XUnoUrlResolver;
import com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap;
import com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory;
import com.sun.star.lang.XMultiServiceFactory;
import com.sun.star.uno.UnoRuntime;
import com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext;

public class Test {



    XMultiServiceFactory ooConnect() {

        final String sConnectionString = "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager";
        // create the initial component context
        XComponentContext rComponentContext = null;
        try {
            rComponentContext = Bootstrap
                    .defaultBootstrap_InitialComponentContext();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        // retrieve the servicemanager from the context
        XMultiComponentFactory rServiceManager = rComponentContext
                .getServiceManager();

        Object objectUrlResolver = null;
        try {
            objectUrlResolver = rServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
                    "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", rComponentContext);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create a new url resolver
        XUnoUrlResolver xurlresolver = (XUnoUrlResolver) UnoRuntime
                .queryInterface(XUnoUrlResolver.class, objectUrlResolver);

        XMultiServiceFactory rOfficeServiceManager = null;
        try {
            // resolve the uno-url
            Object objectInitial = xurlresolver.resolve(sConnectionString);

            rOfficeServiceManager = (XMultiServiceFactory) UnoRuntime
                    .queryInterface(XMultiServiceFactory.class, objectInitial);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return rOfficeServiceManager;
        }
        return rOfficeServiceManager;
    }




    public static void main (String [] args)

    {
        Test test = new Test();

        XMultiServiceFactory serviceFactory = test.ooConnect();
        if(serviceFactory != null)
        {
            System.out.println("YEYEYEYEY");
        }
    }
}
```

why I try to compile this I use this command

```
javac -cp java_uno.jar;juh.jar;jurt.jar;ridl.jar;unoil.jar Test.java
```

it successfully compiles and give me a class.

but When I try to execute the class with below command

java Test, I get below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/comp/helper/Bootstrap
        at Test.ooConnect(Test.java:18)
        at Test.main(Test.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 2 more
```

or if I use this command

```
java -cp .:java_uno.jar;juh.jar;jurt.jar;ridl.jar;unoil.jar Test
```

I get this error
Error: Could not find or load main class Test

any help will be appreciated.

as suggested I changed the run command to

```
java -cp .;java_uno.jar;juh.jar;jurt.jar;ridl.jar;unoil.jar Test
```

now I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no juh in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at com.sun.star.lib.util.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:65)
        at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.defaultBootstrap_InitialComponentContext(Bootstrap.java:199)
        at com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.defaultBootstrap_InitialComponentContext(Bootstrap.java:167)
        at Test.ooConnect(Test.java:18)
        at Test.main(Test.java:64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows class separator in classpath is semicolon (;). For UNIX it is colon (:). You are using both separators in one command line:

```
java -cp .:java_uno.jar;juh.jar;jurt.jar;ridl.jar;unoil.jar Test
```

Since your compilation was good I assume you are on Windows. So, use semicolon for whole path:

```
java -cp .;java_uno.jar;juh.jar;jurt.jar;ridl.jar;unoil.jar Test
```

Comment: Are you sure you had installed all your libraries right? It looks like JUH was not installed correctly. I hope this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path) may help you. At least try to validate somehow that all libraries are fine - for example run some test task from the JUH package. Does it have one?

Comment: According to [Open Office Documentation](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/java.html) you should also double check that you are using  32-bit Java. That could be another reason for incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... It was using 32 bit and my java 64 bit.