# while building alfresco maven project i found one exception no win32netbios in java library path

Tags: alfresco

```
2015-12-19 18:38:41,620  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Win32NetBIOS in java.library.path
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,620  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.jlan.netbios.win32.Win32NetBIOS.<clinit>(Win32NetBIOS.java:834)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.filesys.AbstractServerConfigurationBean.getLocalServerName(AbstractServerConfigurationBean.java:648)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.filesys.AbstractServerConfigurationBean.getLocalServerName(AbstractServerConfigurationBean.java:608)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.filesys.config.ServerConfigurationBean.processCIFSServerConfig(ServerConfigurationBean.java:247)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.filesys.AbstractServerConfigurationBean.init(AbstractServerConfigurationBean.java:450)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.filesys.AbstractServerConfigurationBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractServerConfigurationBean.java:801)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ChildApplicationContext.publishEvent(ChildApplicationContextFactory.java:554)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory$ApplicationContextState.start(ChildApplicationContextFactory.java:809)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.start(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:1018)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.AbstractPropertyBackedBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractPropertyBackedBean.java:557)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:209)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:180)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:948)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,621  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,622  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at com.tradeshift.test.remote.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:73)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main]    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [main] Error accessing Win32 NetBIOS, check DLL is on the path
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'fileServers' subsystem, ID: [fileServers, default] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,623  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,745  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,745  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,846  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,846  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,926  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,927  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,946  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:41,958  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,077  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,178  INFO  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Alfresco JVM - v1.7.0_80-b15; maximum heap size 494.938MB
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,179  WARN  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Alfresco JVM - WARNING - maximum heap size 494.938MB is less than recommended 512MB
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,179  INFO  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Server Mode :UNKNOWN
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,179  INFO  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [main] Alfresco started (Community). Current version: 5.0.0 (c r91299-b145) schema 8,009. Originally installed version: 5.0.0 (c r91299-b145) schema 8,009.
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,186  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default]
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,416  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,416  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Starting 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
 2015-12-19 18:38:42,433  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [main] Startup of 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default] complete
 2015-12-19 18:38:44,069  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [main] Registered 13 Web Scripts (+0 failed), 15 URLs
 2015-12-19 18:38:44,069  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [main] Registered 1 Package Description Documents (+0 failed) 
 2015-12-19 18:38:44,069  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeRegistry] [main] Registered 0 Schema Description Documents (+0 failed) 
 2015-12-19 18:38:44,074  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntimeContainer] [main] Initialised Spring Web Scripts Container Web Script Container (in 203.07327ms)
 2015-12-19 18:38:44,152  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] [main] Registered template processor freemarker for extension ftl
 2015-12-19 18:38:44,156  INFO  [extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] [main] Registered script processor javascript for extension js
 Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 34.146 sec - in org.alfresco.demoamp.test.DemoComponentTest
```

Comment: Do you have the `Win32NetBIOS.dll` on your system? Which OS are you using? Did you check if you have the right configuration to install Alfresco? You should rephrase your question. Right now the quality of your question is rather poor. Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path

Comment: Add more details in question, like what are the things you have tried so far, version of mvn, alfresco etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by coping some dll files from my alfreco bin folder to windows/system32 folder.

files are:
1)Win32NetBIOS.dll

2)Win32NetBIOSx64.dll

3)Win32Utils.dll

4)Win32Utilsx64.dll

[Files Name shown in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fceb2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other reviews that you probably need to rephrase your question because it does not contain all the necessary information.

Having said that, it is possible that the problem you found is the following known issue:

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-11845

As stated in the description of this ticket, you can solve the problem adding the dll to the java.library.path