# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpeg in java.library.path

Tags: java, swing, javax.imageio

We have a JavaWebStart application, which allows to scan images and write them to a file. All works fine but today I've got an exception from a customer, which I cannot understand.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpeg in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter$1.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at de.eurodata.commons.scan.domain.ScanUtils.writeImageToFile(ScanUtils.java:81)
```

This exception is occured on Win7 x86. I've searched for this exception using Google but found only some irrelevant (Linux, Oracle 9i) or unanswered posts.

My question is: can I prevent this problem? Probably another pure Java jpeg plugin for ImageIO (if exists and stable)?

Comment: it seems same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path

Comment: @user101 The basic cause is the same, however this is not a custom DLL, it's the JPEG library that should be bundled with the JRE, used by the standard (`com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg`) JPEG ImageIO plugin. My guess is user has a screwed up JRE installation. Ask him to re-install the JRE, and see if that helps.

Comment: And yes, a pure Java JPEG plugin would solve the issue. If you find one. Tell me if you do. I'm working on one, but don't hold your breath just yet. ;-)