# How to use createX3DFromStream in Java code

Tags: java

I'm making a Java class named `Xj3DTester` which displays `X3D` and `X3DV` files and when I run it, I get the following runtime error message.

```
run:
Mar 23, 2016 12:47:39 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Message: WARNING: antialiasing will be disabled because the DefaultGLCapabilitiesChooser didn't supply it
Mar 23, 2016 12:47:42 PM org.odejava.Odejava <clinit>
SEVERE: Native code library (32 and 64 bit library) failed to load: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no odejava in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no odejava in java.library.path
Warning: The class that you specificed for the physics manager is not a valid instance of PhysicsManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.odejava.Odejava.<clinit>(Odejava.java:103)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.eventmodel.DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager$1.run(DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.java:149)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.eventmodel.DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager$1.run(DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.java:142)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.xj3d.impl.core.eventmodel.DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.<clinit>(DefaultRigidBodyPhysicsManager.java:141)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.browser.OGLBrowserCanvas$4.run(OGLBrowserCanvas.java:1069)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.browser.OGLBrowserCanvas.loadClass(OGLBrowserCanvas.java:1064)
    at org.web3d.vrml.renderer.ogl.browser.OGLBrowserCanvas.initialize(OGLBrowserCanvas.java:694)
    at org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.BrowserJPanel.<init>(BrowserJPanel.java:256)
    at org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DBrowserJPanel.<init>(X3DBrowserJPanel.java:75)
    at org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.createComponent(X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl.java:219)
    at org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(BrowserFactory.java:263)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:42)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)

Message: Device found: Mouse-0
Message: Device found: Keyboard-0
Exception in thread "main" org.web3d.x3d.sai.InvalidURLException: Unable to load any URLS
    at org.web3d.vrml.scripting.external.sai.SAIBrowser.createX3DFromURL(SAIBrowser.java:846)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.<init>(Xj3DTest.java:50)
    at xj3dtest.Xj3DTest.main(Xj3DTest.java:56)
```

And my Java code is as follows.

```
package xj3dtest;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.Browser;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.BrowserFactory;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DComponent;
import org.web3d.x3d.sai.X3DScene;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Xj3DTest extends JFrame {

    public Xj3DTest(String title) {

        super(title);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Setup browser parameters
        HashMap requestedParameters=new HashMap();
        requestedParameters.put("Antialiased",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("TextureQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("PrimitiveQuality","medium");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_InterfaceType","SWING");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_NavbarPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationPosition","TOP");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_LocationReadOnly",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ShowConsole",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_OpenButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ReloadButtonShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_StatusBarShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_FPSShown",TRUE);
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_ContentDirectory","CurrentDirectory");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_AntialiasingQuality","low");
        requestedParameters.put("Xj3D_Culling_Mode", "frustum");

        System.setProperty("x3d.sai.factory.class", "org.xj3d.ui.awt.browser.ogl.X3DOGLBrowserFactoryImpl");
        X3DComponent x3dComponent = BrowserFactory.createX3DComponent(requestedParameters);

        Browser browser = x3dComponent.getBrowser();

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add((javax.swing.JPanel)x3dComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"hafodty_cirlce_1.x3dv"});

        browser.replaceWorld(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Xj3DTest frame = new Xj3DTest("Xj3D test");
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

From what I can see, the error is being caused by the `X3DScene scene = browser.createX3DFromURL(new String[]   {"hafodty_cirlce_1.x3dv"});` line and that I need to use the `createX3DFromStream` method instead of the `createX3DFromURL` method but I don't understand how it works and how to swap them round. I'm using Netbeans 8.1 and I have the X3D and X3DV files saved in the project.

I'm aware that it could seem like I'm asking for help for the `Native code library` and I know how to fix that. I'm asking for help for the section that starts: `Exception in thread...`

Comment: The message "Native code library (32 and 64 bit library) failed to load: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no odejava in java.library.path" is pretty descriptive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError no \*\*\*\*\*.dll in java.library.path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path)

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I get that runtime error while I have the `test.x3d` and `test.x3dv` files in. I'm wondering more about the second bit where it says `Exception in thread...`