# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while trying to load opencv

Tags: java, scala, opencv, sbt

I am trying to use opencv in a Scala application built using sbt and this is my `build.sbt`

```
name := "Marker"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

javaOptions in run += "-Djava.library.path=/home/priyatham/libs/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib"
```

And this the error I am getting when I `sbt run`

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:10)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 13 Sep, 2016 8:40:09 PM
```

What's wrong with the way I am modifying `java.library.path`

EDIT: I did put the `opencv-310.jar` in `Marker/lib` folder

Compiling with `java -Djava.library.path="/home/priyatham/libs/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib"` works though, but not with `sbt run`

Comment: It seems library name issue, error saying opencv_java310 but you are saying opencv-310.jar, are sure this is how it should be/.

Comment: I don't think names are an issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path I am pretty sure you have either wrong path or missing jar.

Comment: This error typically happens when a native-language library is missing. Check the install instructions and look for some .so file that needs to be installed, or whether you need to compile binaries.

Comment: You provide differnt path. Look at first character (`/`)

Comment: I am sorry @talex that was typo here, but it's the same in my code.

Comment: add `fork in run := true`. I think now it tries to run your code in same JVM so `javaOptions` is not applied.

Comment: Thank you so much @talex, that fixed it.

Comment: I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED:

Add `fork in run := true`. I think now it tries to run your code in same JVM so javaOptions is not applied.

Comment: Does `/home/priyatham/libs/opencv-3.1.0/build/lib/libopencv_java310.so` file exists and contains what we expect? Is application have access to it (permissions)?