# How to install jinput in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.library.path, jinput

The last days I searched how to use Controllers like DS4 in java and it got me to jinput. After downloading the zip file. I added the two JARs to the project and tryed to run a test code, that I found in an installtion guide.

The problem is that it says

> no jinput-dx8_64 in java.library.path".

I know there is another Thread for this problem, but I didn't understand it, maybe because of my bad English, maybe because of my knowledge. I tried to fix it by adding the directory of the files to the `jre native library` in eclipse, but it keeps saying the same errors.

Comment: Sometimes a Java library is just a wrapper around a "native" library written in C or C++. In that case, the native library (a .so or .dll file) needs to be accessible to Java when you use the API. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path

Comment: corrected typos

Answer (score 0):

[image: How to include jinput library with the natives]
*This is only one of the many possible way of including external library*

---

Frist you have to download the library jar
[Download from maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.jinput/jinput/2.0.5)

Then you download the natives library for the desired os
[Download from maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.6)

Finally you link both the library (jar) and the natives (dll for windows) in the project

Comment: Do the natives also work for other OS like Linux ARM?

Comment: Any other suggestions on this? I had done what you suggested before getting to this question and still get this from Eclipse: `INFO: Failed to load library: no jinput-linux64 in java.library.path java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-linux64 in java.library.path`. Linked question doesn't really solve it for me either.