# Java Spring Boot WEB API To PCF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pcf, pcfdev

I am trying to Push a Spring Boot third Party Vendor App to a PCF Environment.

PCF is something new to me I tried to fix other issue this one is kind of recurring the whole time.

Kindly advice on the below error.

This is my folder structure.

```
config
META-INF
resources
WEB-INF
descriptor.xml
manifest.yml
pom.xml
ws.bat
```

I am trying to push the whole folder to pcf and start the WEB API in PCF.

1)

```
2018-02-17T17:46:17.46-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  18-Feb-2018 00:46:17 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 10162 ms
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] SEVERE  StandardWrapper.Throwable
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no iomp5 in java.library.path
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.axioma.webservice.servlet.OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.loadThirdPartyBinaryDeps(OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.java:102)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.axioma.webservice.servlet.OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.init(OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.java:47)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] SEVERE  Servlet [OptimizationEnvironmentServlet] in web application [] threw load() exception
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no iomp5 in java.library.path
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.axioma.webservice.servlet.OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.loadThirdPartyBinaryDeps(OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.java:102)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.axioma.webservice.servlet.OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.init(OptimizationEnvironmentServlet.java:47)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext           SEVERE  One or more Servlets failed to load on startup. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext           SEVERE  Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.49-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.50-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  18-Feb-2018 00:46:17 com.axioma.taskscheduler.TaskSchedulerService  - Shutting down Task Scheduler
```

2)

```
2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    Shutting down log4j
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   WARNING The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   WARNING The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   WARNING The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   WARNING The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   WARNING The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   SEVERE  The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.axioma.utils.cache.CacheMap.FixedSizeMapThreadLocal] (value [com.axioma.utils.cache.CacheMap$FixedSizeMapThreadLocal@4066ed8f]) and a value of type [com.axioma.utils.cache.map.FixedSizeCache] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.76-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   SEVERE  The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.axioma.datacontroller.internal.transaction.TransactionManager$1] (value [com.axioma.datacontroller.internal.transaction.TransactionManager$1@5a203167]) and a value of type [com.axioma.db.commons.transaction.TransactionStatus] (value [com.axioma.db.commons.transaction.TransactionStatus@519944b6]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.77-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   SEVERE  The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2aeae36]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.Submitter] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$Submitter@3584d03b]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.77-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   SEVERE  The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1] (value [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1@42ac07a3]) and a value of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityId] (value [7526a24a-417e-4314-9967-4c9b86f2119f-3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.77-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase   SEVERE  The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1@2e18be66]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom@1ce4807d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.77-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deployment of web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 17,816 ms
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.77-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT [CONTAINER] pplicationStartupFailureDetectingLifecycleListener SEVERE  Error: Application '' failed (state = STOPPED): see Tomcat's logs for details. Halting Tomcat.
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.86-0700 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 148
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.86-0700 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
   2018-02-17T17:46:17.90-0700 [CELL/0] OUT Stopping instance 3eaf8f2f-371b-4615-7d1d-2b72
```

Comment: Are you running mvn package and then copying the war or jar to the server and running that?

Comment: First I had a JAR File I pushed that one. Then I extracted the whole jar and pushed still I am getting the same error.applications:  My YML -
  - name: csSampleAPI
    buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
    path: C:\Projects\A\PCF\New\a-websrv
    framework:
      name: standalone
      info:
        mem: 4000M
        description: Standalone Application
        exec:         
    url: csSampleAPI.com
    mem: 4000M    
    host: csSampleAPI
    instances: 1

Comment: I Am not personally running the mvn Package I Got the app from third part vendor who gave me the jar file and jetty runner file

Comment: you should just have to run  java -jar nameOfJar.jar no unpacking needed. but maybe contact the vendor for running instructions.

Comment: I am able to run the app very well in my local with jetty runner . But when it comes to tomcat i am facing issues in my local and my pcf runs in tomcat

Comment: @Venk Can you post POM.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no iomp5 in java.library.path` <-- this is the issue.
whatever is in your normal process of running locally has that library available.
see here for solution [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError no *****.dll in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path)