# Android Studio fails to open

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio was just working fine. i didn't used for 3 days and when i came to open it again this message pops up. Can anyone help, Plz ?!

[image]

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: You should just re-install the Android Studio.

Comment: version 3.1 
is there any other solution beside reinstalling it ?!

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path

Comment: Isn't 3.1 still in Beta? just go with stable version 3.0.1

Comment: Man you only need to add some text in idea.properties

Comment: I already answered.

Comment: "Man you only need to add some text in idea.properties"
How can i do this?!

Comment: I answered. Watch the answer

Comment: I could give you downvote, but i not done it. So learn to find solutions in internet. Than ask here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the location in `C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties` (or wherever you installed Android Studio)
2. Open the `idea.properties` file with any text editor
3. Add the following code: `disable.android.first.run=true`
4. Save as file on desktop
5. Go to `C:\Program files\Android\Android Studio\bin`
6. Paste the file which we saved as on desktop
7. Replace `idea.properties` file
8. Start Android Studio