# how to load native java library

Tags: java

I am trying to load a dll native library using `System.load` method, but it doesn't help, it throws exception.

Here is code:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import one.xmpp.server.network.BigResponseServer;

public class main {
    static {
        System.load("D:\\one-xmpp-proxy-master\\one-xmpp-proxy-master\\libs\\tcnative-1.dll");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("tcnative-1.dll");     
    }
}
```

The program throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tcnative-1.dll in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at test.main.main(main.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order for `System.loadLibrary()` to work, the library (on Windows,
>   a DLL) must be in a directory somewhere on your `PATH` or on a path
>   listed in the `java.library.path` system property (so you can launch
>   Java like `java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir`).

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403808/1602555) for full explanation, make sure to upvote the author.

Comment: kdowbecki , i don't understand , can you explain  more clearly? You mean that i must load all dll files in java folder?

Comment: Edited the answer and left the link to full answer in other question.

Comment: Don't answer questions with only a quote from an answer of another question, if you can do that, it is a sign you should flag/vote to close as a duplicate of that question.