# Can Spring boot load dll library?

Tags: java, spring, dll

I have a dll file used to communicate with a card reader. In normal java project, I could load and use the library normally but when I try to use the same class in a Spring Boot project, the method does not seem to work.

The class looks like this:

```
public class cardfunction {

public native String GetDLLVersion();
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("DoorLock");
}

public native String CancelCard();
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("DoorLock");
}
}
```

These methods works fine but if I use this class in a Spring boot project, the dll is not working any more:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    cardfunction fc = new cardfunction();
    int initialize = fc.initializeUSB();
    String dellVer = fc.GetDLLVersion();
    String hotelCode = fc.GetHotelSystemCode();
    fc.CloseUSB();
    return "initialize : " + initialize + " dllVer: " + dellVer + " hotelCode: " + hotelCode;
}
```

This is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.hotel.card.cardfunction.initializeUSB()I
at com.hotel.card.cardfunction.initializeUSB(Native Method) ~[classes/:na]
```

[image]

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path