# Empty JavaFX window on some systems

Tags: javafx, gluon, graalvm-native-image

I created a simple JavaFX application that compiles to binary using GraalVM with the Gluon maven plugin. However, the binary shows an empty window on some systems (for example, a fresh installed linux desktop). The compilation was made using a [Github Action](https://github.com/arturolinares/ColorSelectorFX/blob/master/.github/workflows/linux.yml) which runs `mvn -Pdesktop gluonfx:build gluonfx:package`.

Why does the binary only runs on some Linux systems?

The pom.xml configuration ([full file here](https://github.com/arturolinares/ColorSelectorFX/blob/master/pom.xml)):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
<artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.4</version>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.alinares.colorselectorfx.App</mainClass>
    <enableSWRendering>true</enableSWRendering>
    <nativeImageArgs>
          <arg>-Dprism.verbose=true</arg>
    </nativeImageArgs>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

[image: Screenshot of with errors]

Stacktrace:

```
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @1edfedf1'
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.initialize(III)V [symbol: Java_com_sun_pisces_JavaSurface_initialize or Java_com_sun_pisces_JavaSurface_initialize__III]
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:153)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:57)
    at com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.initialize(JavaSurface.java)
    at com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.<init>(JavaSurface.java:45)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWRTTexture.<init>(SWRTTexture.java:51)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWResourceFactory.createRTTexture(SWResourceFactory.java:135)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWResourceFactory.createRTTexture(SWResourceFactory.java:124)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(UploadingPainter.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:552)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
```

[image: SS of the app]

**Update**: Running the binary with `-Dprism.verbose=true`:

```
Aug 19, 2021 10:58:33 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @11bd803'
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.X11GLFactory
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Failed Graphics Hardware Qualifier check.
System GPU doesn't meet the es2 pipe requirement
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
 vsync: true vpipe: false
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.initialize(III)V [symbol: Java_com_sun_pisces_JavaSurface_initialize or Java_com_sun_pisces_JavaSurface_initialize__III]
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage.getOrFindEntryPoint(JNINativeLinkage.java:153)
    at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.nativeCallAddress(JNIGeneratedMethodSupport.java:57)
    at com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.initialize(JavaSurface.java)
    at com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.<init>(JavaSurface.java:45)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWRTTexture.<init>(SWRTTexture.java:51)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWResourceFactory.createRTTexture(SWResourceFactory.java:135)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWResourceFactory.createRTTexture(SWResourceFactory.java:124)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.UploadingPainter.run(UploadingPainter.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:567)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:192)
```

I added `<enableSWRendering>true</enableSWRendering>` to the [pom.xml](https://github.com/arturolinares/ColorSelectorFX/commit/8bdc2942234e1f151a589447d587e02dde24982a) and added `com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.initialize` to [reflect-config.json](https://github.com/arturolinares/ColorSelectorFX/commit/e163a57f18b279051972c3bfcf2b8d1d052fdfcd#diff-cc783b387f34bc02ac5f61716d44f91c1b614c06c7fab75ff427c71503ef4a4bR38) and [jni-config.json](https://github.com/arturolinares/ColorSelectorFX/commit/e163a57f18b279051972c3bfcf2b8d1d052fdfcd#diff-14a0b1c2d0484d1197837b27a7ce3a9495dc3b6ec2e5dbb1132ffe03fd0d6d69R87) (after running `gluonfx:runagent`).

Comment: See related: [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path).   A native library could not be loaded.  How to resolve this for your particular configuration, I do not know.  Perhaps you are trying to run your application on a platform that gluon does not support (again I do not know).

Comment: Can you run `mvn gluonfx:runagent`? See [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_gluonfxrunagent). It should create the config files for native-image that include the missing JNI method for `com.sun.pisces.JavaSurface.initialize`. You can add `<arg>-Dprism.order=sw</arg>` to your pom to force `sw`.

Comment: @JoséPereda Unfortunately, it didn't work. I updated the question with your suggestions to the gluon plugin configuration (I'm using maven) and the config file updates for JNI. Maybe I'm not editing the correct JNI config file?

Comment: You need to change `<nativeImageArgs>` to `<runtimeArgs>`, and add `<options><option>-Dprism.order=sw</option></options>` to the JavaFX maven plugin before you call `gluonfx:runagent`. Either way, it still fails on Linux, but works fine on Mac.

Comment: "Either way, it still fails on Linux, but works fine on Mac." If I understand correctly, if there is no hardware acceleration in Linux the native binary will not render the app?

Comment: Gluon Substrate has recently added a GraalVM `Feature` for [Linux](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/commit/1bd2dae341807e5008e9c609771438bab6a32b08), and that is part of GluonFX plugin 1.0.4. [Currently](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/feature/GluonFeature.java#L66) it is missing the `com.sun.pisces` package, and that causes the exception. If you try with GluonFX plugin 1.0.3 it will work. Can you file an issue [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues)?

Comment: Filed it myself: https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/990

Comment: Thanks for all your help @JoséPereda!